# Why does "return ERROR" only work with exceptions?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, error-handling, struts2

In the struts.xml I use:

```
<result name="error">error</result>
```

Then in my action I use:

```
addActionError("ERROR RETURNED");
return ERROR;
```

When I submit the form then it just goes to a blank page and does nothing. However, if I FORCE an exception to be thrown in the action then it goes to the error page and shows the ActionError message. So am I doing this wrong? If so, how should I tell struts to show an error page using "if statements" instead of relying solely on expensive try catches?

Please view edits below for more details.

**EDIT 1:**

I'm using struts 2 version: 2.1.8.1

**EDIT 2:**

For example, here is my action code that I'm using to test:

```
String test = "";
int number = 0;
        try {
        if (number == 1) {
            test = SUCCESS;
        } else if (number == 2) {
            addActionError("ERROR RETURNED?");
            test = ERROR;
        } else if (number == 3) {
            addActionError("ERROR RETURNED?");
            test = INPUT;
        } else {
            test = LOGIN;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addActionError("ERROR RETURNED? " + e);
        }
        return test;
```

Here is my number.jsp code:

```
<s:form action="number_save" method="post">
     <s:textfield name="number" label="Enter number" />
</s:form>
<s:actionerror />
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is a longer version of my struts.xml:

```
 <action name="number" method="numberCreate" class="NumberActionBean">
       <result>number.jsp</result>
 </action>

<action name="error">
    <result>error.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="number_save" method="numberSave" class="NumberActionBean">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">index</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirect">number</result>
            <result name="error">error</result>
            <result name="login" type="redirect">login</result>
            <result name="none">number</result>
</action>
```

**EDIT 4:**

My `error.jsp` is simply a `<s:actionerror />` tag with the general taglibs and html tags...

**Conclusion**

I'm unable to show `AddActionError` messages unless there's an exception. I am unable to use `if` statements in my action.

Comment: when its going to blank page, is there anything on server console?

Comment: what do you expect to happen on the form submit? show us the relevant struts mappings and some action code.

Comment: moreover i am wondering, what this `error` inside the result configuration? is it a JSP page or what?

Comment: @ThreaT: can you how the error.jsp?

Comment: @ThreaT: as per your post , you said on error its only showing a blank page and no error message which u have set in your action so i am wondering what all there is you error.jsp, you edit2 does not seems to contain error.jsp or m i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution summary:

## 1

do not redirect "error" as a ction, just use

```
<result name="error"> **error.jsp** </result>
```

## 2

if you rly wanna redict error action with error messages. check this link out: [implement-message-store-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/message-store-interceptor.html)

Comment: You can remove the 1st one as it's incorrect. I mentioned that I mapped error to error.jsp so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do this:

```
<result name="error">error.jsp</result>
```

then in the error.jsp:

```
<s:actionerror/>
```

i am not sure, if you only type "error" instead of "error.jsp" as a result, struts tread "error" as an action, so you won't get you error message.

best, j

for your EDIT 3:

```
<action name="error">
  <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="number_save">
  <result name="error" type="redirectAction">error</result>
</action>
```

Comment: But shouldn't you change error result for action `number_save` too, to point at error.jsp? That's where it's failing, it seems: `<result name="error">error</result>` should be `<result name="error">error.jsp</result>`.

Comment: Again: you need it _inside the action `number_save`_! So here: <action name="**number_save**" method="numberSave" class="NumberActionBean">...            <result name="error"> **error.jsp** </result>...</action>

Comment: Ah, you mean it should redirect to action `error` that is mapped to `error.jsp`. I see. I'd still give it a go if I were you :)

Comment: @ThreaT please try to add action type "redirectAction"

Comment: @ThreaT hehe, just like i mentioned before, so why don't u just use error.jsp, do not try to "redirect" the action. I just googled 4 u, here is the reference, if u rly wanna do this, chek this out: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/message-store-interceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern here is "expensive try catches" I would not proceed with this. It's sub-optimization and it will introduce complexity that in the long run will be more costly to maintain than what you gain in milliseconds of performance.

A try-block does not add any significant cost overhead, unless an exception is actually thrown. And when we talk about "significant overhead" in this context, it's in the low milliseconds range.

And why are you trying to optimize an error-page? It's not like that's something that will be called often.

Comment: Optimise an error page? I'm trying to avoid try catches as far as possible and use `if` statements instead. If I can do a basic `if` check and avoid the same exception being thrown for every user on the server then why not? It's not that it's the only thing running, the idea is to save resources wherever we can otherwise we run into slow systems at a later stage. The flaw in your logic is that you're assuming that there are resources to be wasted from the get-go.

Comment: Again, entering a try-block doesn't incur any significant cost. The performance/resource cost is when an exception is actually thrown and caught. So assuming you're are not using exceptions for basic flow-control, you are in fact optimizing for the cases where exceptions are really thrown, which would be in case of error. But far be it for me to dictate where you're spending your development resources. Just saying that bending frameworks to conform and going against established patterns comes with a cost, both in development and in maintenance.

Comment: Try catches definitely are expensive. Do some research, do some tests - I did mine. They aren't scalable enough to be used freely as many would like to believe. Your answer is false because, again, it assumes that there are resources to waste. No "framework bending" is required because there ARE ways to do what I'm trying to achieve. If you read the answer I selected as correct then you would know that.

Comment: Again, try/catches are **NOT** expensive, unless an exception is actually thrown. I don't know what tests and/or research you have been doing, but I question your results. On an execution level, an unused try/catch have about the same instruction density as an if/else.

Comment: If you think that they are not expensive then why don't you go exhaust your applications with them and see where it gets you? Obviously no one is going to over-use them but the point is that they *ARE* expensive.

Comment: @ThreaT Well, let's agree to disagree. As I'll most likely never come in contact with any application you build and you'll never come in contact with anything I build, any argument is fairly moot anyway ;)

Comment: Okay let's agree to disagree but well, while you'll definitely come into contact with something I build, I'm not sure that I'll come into contact with something you build.